# Singletons and class loaders in Tomcat web applications

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, classloader

I have been doing a lot of research online but can't seem to find a definitive answer to my question which is why I turned to the experts on this site.

When developing with java and Tomcat I have a Singleton class that handles my database connection. So the question is when different users connect to my web application, and my server side java code executes does it get its own singleton class?

For example:
User A logs into my site. An instance of my singleton is created. 
User B logs into my site, does the same object (singleton) persist between the two executions of the java code? or is each execution for user A and user B get different singletons?

thank you.

Comment: You need to provide a code sample. Not a chance of giving you an accurate answer without. Are you using Spring? How do you create your singletons?

Comment: Why on earth would you waste time writing a singleton to manage database connections when you could create a connection pool with Tomcat and let it do the work?

Comment: I was just using database connection as an example. Yes I agree a bad example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A singleton means a single instance per JVM (per classloader, to be precise). Tomcat does not have seperate environment per user. Instead, it has seperate classloader (and hence separate environment) per web application. Hence, no matter how many users are connected the server side is a single environment and this environment has a single instance of your singleton class which is shared by all the classes loaded in that environment.

Answer (score 5):

A singleton, stored in a static field, is unique per classloader. So all users of your web application on a tomcat instance would be using the same singleton.

Comment: This precisely the answer I was looking for. Straight to the point, simple and answers exactly the question I had. Thank you.